# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyarrow' with satisfied requirements

Tags: pyarrow

I am trying to run this command in Jupyter Notebook: import pyarrow, get the same error: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyarrow'

I have installed it already with pip3 and brew also. So when I ran pip3install pyarrow it says requirements are already satisfied. All other libraries I have installed runs with no issues from the same directory.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an odd one, for sure. I am not familiar enough with pyarrow to know why the following worked.

From [the docs](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/install.html), If I do `pip3 install pyarrow` and run `pip3 list`, `pyarrow` shows up in the list but I cannot seem to `import` it from the python CLI. Yet, if I also run `conda install -c conda-forge pyarrow`, installing all of it's dependencies, now jupyter notebook can import it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a venv? Try running `jupyter kernelspec list` in your console and make sure your kernel is running in the environment you're expecting it to be.

https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/2359 (discussion about this here)